# XCode6 Interface Builder iPad issues

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode6

I am trying to build a view controller nib using XCode 6 Interface Builder. Currently my view controller contains only a view that I have set a dark gray background color. When I load it in an iPhone simulator, everything works as expected, that is the view fills the screen with the dark gray background color. When I load in iPad, the view is shifted off to the left and upward.

For iPhone size classes, I am using w:Compact h:Regular.

For iPad size classes I am using w:Regular h:Any.

In the Interface Builder preview, both iPhone and iPad look as they should.

Here is what it looks like in the iPad simulator:

[image]

Something else worth noting. The view controller shown in the image is the entire view controller. It's not just partially visible. 
Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: yes, but have not set any constraints. Just set the default view which I assume fills he entire control.

Comment: With out the constraints, your output is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using autolayout with well setted constraints ?
It seems your view controller is 300x300 pixels as in the any Size Class definition.

Try to look at a button in your bottom right xib editor that looks like this
**`|-□-|`**

If you don't set any constraint, your view is binded to no layout and **will not adapt at all**.

You have to set constraints to define position *(x, y)* and size *(width, height)* with your constraints in order to make it adapting to your view controller without ambiguity.
In your example, you just have to set every border of your view *(top, left, right bottom)* to match the borders of its superview.

Answer (score 0):

Please apply constraint TOP-RIGHT-LEFT-BOTTOM